Как запустить файл с xml в браузере?
Создал файл по типу html:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xslt"?>
<html xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<marc:collection xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
<marc:record>
  <marc:leader>01025nam a22001931i 4500</marc:leader>
  <marc:controlfield tag="001">003903814</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="005">20181212130348.0</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="008">060620s1889    ru b   ||     ||| ||rus d</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="017">
    <marc:subfield code="a">27330-47</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
  <marc:datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="035">
    <marc:subfield code="a">(NLR)rc\1504666</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
  <marc:datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="040">
    <marc:subfield code="a">RuMoRGB</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="b">rus</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="c">Prosoft-M</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="e">rcr</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
  <marc:datafield ind1="0" ind2=" " tag="041">
    <marc:subfield code="a">rus</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
  <marc:datafield ind1="1" ind2="0" tag="245">
    <marc:subfield code="a">Тираспольский уезд :</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="b">(Стат.-экон. описание уезда)</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
  <marc:datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="260">
    <marc:subfield code="c">1889</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
  <marc:datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="300">
    <marc:subfield code="a">394 с. разд. паг., 1 карт.</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
  <marc:datafield ind1="1" ind2="8" tag="773">
    <marc:subfield code="7">nnam</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="t">Материалы для оценки земель Херсонской губернии / Сост. Стат. отд-нием при Херсон. губ. зем. управе. Т. 4</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="d">Херсон : тип. Н.О. Ващенко, 1883-1890</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="h">25</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="w">003512966</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
  <marc:datafield ind1="4" ind2=" " tag="852">
    <marc:subfield code="a">РГБ</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="b">FB</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="c">D19S</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="j">S 13/320</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="x">90</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
  <marc:datafield ind1="4" ind2=" " tag="852">
    <marc:subfield code="a">РГБ</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="b">FB</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="c">D17N</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="j">U 470/44</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="x">90</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
  <marc:datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="LKR">
    <marc:subfield code="a">UP</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="l">RSL01</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="b">003512966</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="m">Тираспольский уезд : (Стат.-экон. описание уезда)</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="n">Материалы для оценки земель Херсонской губернии /</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
</marc:record>
</marc:collection>
</html>

и создал файл с расширением xlst чтоб преобразовывал данные с xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Шаблон для корневого элемента -->
<xsl:template match="/html">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Библиографическая запись</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Библиографическая запись</h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="marc:collection/marc:record"/>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Шаблон для отображения записи -->
<xsl:template match="marc:record">
<div>
  <h2>Основная информация</h2>
  <p>
    <strong>Заголовок:</strong>
    <xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag='245']/marc:subfield[@code='a']"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag='245']/marc:subfield[@code='b']"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Год издания:</strong>
    <xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag='260']/marc:subfield[@code='c']"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Язык:</strong>
    <xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag='041']/marc:subfield[@code='a']"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Объем:</strong>
    <xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag='300']/marc:subfield[@code='a']"/>
  </p>

  <h2>Сведения о публикации</h2>
  <p>
    <strong>Серия:</strong>
    <xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag='773']/marc:subfield[@code='t']"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Издательство:</strong>
    <xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag='773']/marc:subfield[@code='d']"/>
  </p>

  <h2>Местоположение и коды хранения</h2>
  <xsl:for-each select="marc:datafield[@tag='852']">
    <p>
      <strong>Местоположение:</strong> <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='a']"/> (<xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='b']"/>)
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Шифр хранения:</strong>
      <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='j']"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:for-each>
</div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Запускаю файл xml в яндексе и ничего не получаю в ответ, прочитал многие выводы об этом якобы браузер не переваривает xlst преобразования, и нельзя ее запустить и посмотреть в браузере?

Всё работает, причём именно в яндексе: https://i.sstatic.net/fiEtB6ta.png

Возможно, ваша ошибка в том, что вы получаете доступ к файлам не через веб-сервер

а здесь по подробнее можно я просто xml файл открываю через проводник к браузеру и все где и какой доступ не имею понятия
